# Render template according to URL parameter

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have the following situation: I need to render a template according to the provided URL parameter. Example:

```
http://localhost:9000/abc -> renders abc.scala.html
http://localhost:9000/def -> renders def.scala.html
```

The simplest solution would be to define these requirements in the **routes** file:

```
GET /abc     controllers.Application.abc()
GET /def     controllers.Application.def()
...
```

and then in the Application controller:

```
public static Result abc() {
    return ok(abc.render());
}
```

But I am looking for a more 'generic' solution. Like this:

```
GET /:myparameter     controllers.Application.test(myparameter: String)
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to 'call' the corresponding view in my controller. I was thinking about some kind of a map where each parameter maps to a view but with no success. I tried it like this

```
Map<String, play.api.templates.Html>
```

of course this only provides me with the HTML content and not the "Template" I want to render.

**Info:** I am using Play 2 with Java

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the proposal you've suggested yourself of maintaining a map of parameter values to `Html` types is a viable option:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    private static final Map<String, Html> views = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        views.put("abc", abc.render());
        views.put("def", def.render());
        ...
    }

    public static Result test(final String myparameter) {

        final Html view = views.get(myparameter);
        if (view != null) {
            return ok(view);
        } else {
            // Unsupported parameter
            return badRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above all templates are pre-rendered in a static block. Judging by the way you've described your problem, it doesn't seem that any of your templates take in any parameters, so this approach of rendering templates early should work for you.

However, it may be the case that you do/will have templates that take in parameters and can't be rendered early. In this case, another approach you could take is a solution that uses action composition:

```
/*
 * This action is composed of many different actions that form a 
 * chain of responsibility.
 */
@Abc
@Def
...
public static Result test(final String myparameter) {
    ....
}
```

This approach is a bit more future-proof but involves more code and classes and is perhaps not as generic as what you're presently looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I am probably going to use this option. But is there any way to store only the 'reference' to the template in the map instead of the 'compiled html'? Something like:
`Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>()`
`map.put("abc", abc)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.7, you can use a simple switch

```
public static Result test(final String myparameter) {

    switch(myparameter){
        case "abc":
          //Initialize x,y
          abc.render(x,y);
          break;
        case "def":
          //Initialize x,y,z
          defview.render(x,y,z);
          break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how to do this with reflection. As the above methods are not practical if you have an unknown number of templates and/or don't want to update the code everytime you add a template..

className is the absolute path to the template you wish to render

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Method renderMethod = clazz.getMethod("render");
Object result = renderMethod.invoke(null);

return ok((Html) result);
```